# ASP.net GridView Hyperlink not working

Tags: asp.net

I have a problem with my `GridView`. I have a `HyperlinkField` to redirect and edit items. But when the code is running, the field does not work like a Hyperlink.

My code is the following:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="IdPerfil,Codigo,Version,Titulo,Descripcion,FechaVigencia,Id,IdUsuario,IdSeccion,IdSubcategoria" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="PerfilesPuesto_Editar.aspx?IdPerfil={0}&amp;Codigo={1}&amp;Version={2}&amp;Titulo={3}&amp;Descripcion={4}&amp;FechaVigencia={5}&amp;Id={6}&amp;IdUsuario={7}&amp;IdSeccion={8}&amp;IdSubcategoria={9}" Text="Editar" runat="server"/>
```

The 'Editar' Field should be a hyperlink:
[image]

BTW, some words in the code are Spanish, I hope it does not confuse you.
Can anyone tell me how to fix it?

Comment: Could you show us the generated html?

Comment: Use the browser's developer tool to see the generated html output,

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, it should work. The worst case you can try with [TemplateColumn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatecolumn(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
<asp:TemplateColumn>
    <ItemTemplate>                                
        <a href='<%# string.Format("PerfilesPuesto_Editar.aspx?IdPerfil={0}&Codigo={1}&Version={2}&Titulo={3}&Descripcion={4}&FechaVigencia={5}&Id={6}&IdUsuario={7}&IdSeccion={8}&IdSubcategoria={9}", 
            Eval("IdPerfil"),Eval("Codigo"),Eval("Version"),Eval("Titulo"),Eval("Descripcion"),Eval("FechaVigencia"),Eval("Id"),Eval("IdUsuario"),Eval("IdSeccion"),Eval("IdSubcategoria")) %>'>
            Editar
        </a>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

Comment: the problem is that my Visual Studio does not recognize the TemplateColumn

Comment: Could you please it inside `<Cloumns>` tag like the rest?

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv_PerfilesPuesto" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="IdPerfil" OnRowCommand="gv_PerfilesPuesto_RowCommand1" OnRowDataBound="gv_PerfilesPuesto_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="IdPerfil" HeaderText="Id Perfil" Visible="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Codigo" HeaderText="Codigo" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Version" HeaderText="Version" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Titulo" HeaderText="Titulo" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Descripcion" HeaderText="Descripcion" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FechaVigencia" HeaderText="Fecha Vigencia" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="IdUsuario" Visible="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Administrador" HeaderText="Administrador" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="IdUsuario" HeaderText="IdUsuario" Visible="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Responsable" HeaderText="Responsable" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="IdSeccion" HeaderText="IdSeccion" Visible="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Seccion" HeaderText="Seccion" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="IdSubcategoria" HeaderText="IdSubcategoria" Visible="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="SubCategoria" HeaderText="SubCategoria" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="IdArchivo" HeaderText="IdArchivo" Visible="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Archivo" HeaderText="Archivo" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="IdEstado" HeaderText="IdEstado" Visible="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Nombre" HeaderText="Estado" />
        <asp:ButtonField CommandName="Aprobado" HeaderText="Aprobado" Text="Aprobado" ButtonType="Button" />
        <asp:ButtonField CommandName="Obsoleto" HeaderText="Obsoleto" Text="Obsoleto" ButtonType="Button" />
        <asp:ButtonField CommandName="Descargar" HeaderText="Archivo" Text="Descargar" ButtonType="Button" />
        <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="IdPerfil,Codigo,Version,Titulo,Descripcion,FechaVigencia,Id,IdUsuario,IdSeccion,IdSubcategoria"
             DataNavigateUrlFormatString="PerfilesPuesto_Editar.aspx?IdPerfil={0}&amp;Codigo={1}&amp;Version={2}&amp;Titulo={3}&amp;Descripcion={4}&amp;FechaVigencia={5}&amp;Id={6}&amp;IdUsuario={7}&amp;IdSeccion={8}&amp;IdSubcategoria={9}" Text="Editar" runat="server"/>
        <asp:ButtonField CommandName="Eliminar" Text="Eliminar" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

This is the whole GV code. Not sure if it helps